# What does my boss mean

Tags: meaning-in-context

When I had my 1:1 with my boss today, I told him at the end of the meeting that I would start my vacation after today. He said "Try to be relax and enjoy your vacation". I replied "Sure I will". Then he said "No. You won't. Nice try though". What did he mean by "No. You won't. Nice try though"? Was he just joking?

Comment: Based *purely* on the exchange (and not knowing more about the context or history of the conversation), it sounds to me more like he was saying that he wasn't giving you permission to go on vacation. That *nice try* was in reference to you pulling a fast one on him and simply telling him you were going on vacation tomorrow. Of course, if it was already a given that you *were* going on vacation, then the first comment makes sense. (Although I find *nice try* to be an odd thing to say, if it was meant that way.)

Comment: My guess.  He knows your personality well enough to tell that you will never be able to relax and enjoy anything!

Comment: Whatever the boss may have meant was awkwardly expressed and does not illustrate any general feature of English language and usage.

Answer (score 0):

**nice try**  [M. Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nice%20try)

> —usually used in an ironic way to say that an attempt at something was
>   not very good or was not a nice thing to do

Meaning, in the limited context given in this question: Nice try though. You will not enjoy your vacation because of x!